# Find coset of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, sagemath

I have a vector subspace $V$ of dimension 60 of $\mathbb{F}_2^{100}$. Now I also have a vector $a$.
How to find $b$ such that $a \in b+V$? Is there any algorithm in Sagemath for this?

Comment: What is the definition of $V$?

Comment: If $V$ was meant to be $U$, then there is a very trivial algorithm: just set $b=a$.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited now.

Comment: Take any $b$ in $a+V$. The value $b=a$ is for instance ok... Please explain which is the real problem behind this question, there must be a missing condition on $b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I missed that I can take b=a.